# How to make gcc accept spaces in path

Tags: windows, gcc

I'm trying to build qt5 with gcc on Windows, but I came across following problem:
I have path to directx sdk: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010), and this g++ cannot deal with it, I'm getting:
[image]

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 5):

It's not gcc's fault, it's your shell/terminal/builder program that's passing all of those as separate arguments.  Add some `""` around it on on your command line.  It's already correct for the earlier copy of that `-L` flag on the command line you've shown.